My unique ID is not copying down when using arrayformula
Hi I am using the following formula to create a unique row id using values in other cells in my Google Sheet. When I add arrayformula it does not copy down.  What am I doing wrong?
Works
=B2&""&SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(C2,3),"***","AGN")&TEXT(COUNTIFS(B$2:B2,B2),"00")

Will not copy down:
=ARRAYFORMULA(B2&""&SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(C2,3),"***","AGN")&TEXT(COUNTIFS(B$2:B2,B2),"00"))



Welcome to Web Applications Stack Exchange. Please [edit] your question and insert a table of sample data together with another table that shows your manually entered desired results. Also consider sharing a publicly editable sample spreadsheet. There is a blank sheet maker that lets you share safely.

Use open-ended references, like this:
=arrayformula( 
  if(len(B2:B), 
    B2:B & substitute(left(C2:C, 3), "***", "AGN") & 
    text(countifs(B2:B, B2:B, row(B2:B), "<=" & row(B2:B)), "00"), 
    iferror(ø) 
  ) 
)

See arrayformula().

Use byrow().

I gather that this is your first question at Stack Exchange. See What should I do when someone answers my question?

Please observe that Stack Exchange sites are not "help forums" nor "discussion boards" but wiki sites that use the Q&A format. See Ask questions, get answers, no distractions. Ask only one question per post. Post a new question instead.
